# Django-tables2 pagination

Tags: django, django-tables2, django-pagination

While using django-tables2 I couldn't find how I paginate the table. On the [documentation](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/pagination.html) It says enough to set the table for view but doesn't work.

```
class TableView(SingleTableView):
    model = TableModel
    table_class = MyTable
    template_name = "table.html"
```

Comment: Did you try `table_data = TableModel.objects.all()`?

Comment: Yes. Should I use 'paginate_by ="" ' ?

Comment: Django provides [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a view that inherits from SingleTableView, you must specify in the Meta class of your table_class the per_page attribute with the value of objects per page.

Example:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('name', 'age')
    per_page = 5
```